# UICollectionView + flowlayout scroll to item 1

Tags: ios, uicollectionview, flowlayout

I have a UICollectionView using UICollectionViewFlowLayout with scroll direction set to vertical.

When I call:

```
[colllectionView scrollToItemAtIndexPath:[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]
                       atScrollPosition:UICollectionViewPositionCenteredVertically
                               animated:YES];
```

It scrolls to item 0 instead.

This works in horizontal mode and works for all other items in the collection.

Answer (score 0):

You want `[NSIndexPath indexPathForItem:1 inSection:0]`. If you were reading the header for `NSIndexPath`, you won’t find it there, because it’s an iOS-specific category in `UICollectionView.h`. There is an equivalent version for rows and sections in `UITableView.h`.

Comment: You're right, that was me writing the snippet by hand rather than looking at the code I was running.

Comment: Oh, so that didn’t fix it? And here I thought I was being all clever ;)

Comment: Though your answer is 100% correct they actually are the same ;) they call the same underlying method ;) unfortunately I cannot find the reference right now but I read it somewhere (I think NSHipster or objc.in or similar).